Executing Oracle User Function Truncating the Result
I am trying to run an Oracle user function that returns a SQL query. This SQL Query is used for an SSRS report. I want to get the exact query that the report sends to the Oracle DB.
I am trying to query the following user function to get the exact SQL query that the report sends:
SELECT REPORT_PREPARE_QUERY('Report Name', 1, 12345678) as Test FROM DUAL;
When the above statement executes, it only returns a truncated result:
"
WITH CTE
AS (
    select distinct A.First, A.Second, A."


The above query is stored in another table. Of course, I can go to that table and get the full query, but the query has parameters passed by the report, for example like this
" :Test_Parameter ", and I want the exact query with parameters passed by the report.
These are the function parameters:
create or replace function          REPORT_PREPARE_QUERY (
    report_name varchar2,
    query_num number,
    transaction_num number,
    empty_dataset number default 0
) RETURN clob
AS
    report_query clob;
    report_num number;
    report_filters clob;


I am using Oracle SQL Developer and this is the DB version:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0
I have tried to use the following query to get history, but it also truncates (SQL_Text column) the result of the query sent:
 select v.SQL_TEXT,
           v.PARSING_SCHEMA_NAME,
           v.FIRST_LOAD_TIME,
           v.DISK_READS,
           v.ROWS_PROCESSED,
           v.ELAPSED_TIME,
           v.service
      from v$sql v

order by FIRST_LOAD_TIME DESC ;

--This does not update when the report runs
select FIRST_LOAD_TIME, SQL_TEXT from v$sqlarea 
order by FIRST_LOAD_TIME desc


Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE, CREATE PROCEDUREandINSERT` statements for your sample data; an English explanation of the logic you are trying to implement; and the expected output. Looking at fiddle it does not truncate the results but you have not provided the code for your procedure so it is difficult to comment on why the procedure is not generating your desired output when we cannot see it.

v$sql.sql_text is intentionally truncated so it can be handled easily as a varchar2 instead of a clob. If you want the full text, use v$sql.sql_fulltext instead. As for your function, you'd need to look into the code of your function and ensure it is actually returning the entire text. Also be sure it isn't simply your client showing you the first part and requiring you to click on something to bring up a window to see the full text. Most clients have a preview feature for handling CLOB columns.

SQL Developer (and SQL*Plus etc) default to only showing you 80 characters of a CLOB or long column when you run as a script. Run set long 500 or some other large number first to see more. Or run as a statement and get the whole value from the query result grid.

There are a few possible duplicates: this or this or this or others. And you may need to set longchunksize too.

Setting longchunksize and set long helped. Instead of 'Run Statement', I ran script and it produced the full query result. These are the settings I used: set termout off
set verify off
set trimspool on
set linesize 200
set longchunksize 200000
set long 200000
set pages 0
column txt format a120 Thank you all for input! It really helped
